# Positive matrices from positive linear functionals.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $C=\sum\limits_{r=1}^K A_r \otimes B_r$, for elements $\{ A_r\}_r^K $ and $\{B_r\}_r^K$ of $C^*$ algebras $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, respectively; then if $\sigma$ is a positive linear functional of $\mathscr{B}$, that is $\sigma(D^*D) \geq 0, \,\forall \, D\in \mathscr{B}$, then if one were to calculate:

$$(_\mathscr{A} \otimes \sigma)(C^*C) = \sum_{r,s=1}^K A_r^*A_s\sigma(B_r^*B_s)$$
where $(_\mathscr{A} \otimes \sigma):\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathscr{B} \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ is given by the partial application of the functional to the $\mathscr{B}$ components of each element of $\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathscr{B}$.

Then why can it be said that $\sigma(B_r^*B_s)$ can be seen as the positve components of a positive matrix $M_{rs} = \sigma(B_r^*B_s)$ ? ($M \in \text{Mat}_{K \times K}(\mathbb{C})$) The positivity of $\sigma$ shouldn't apply only if it were $\sigma(B_r^*B_r)$ instead of $\sigma(B_r^*B_s)$?

Also, how can I get that:
$$S_{rs} = \sigma(B_r^*B_s)-\overline{\sigma(B_r)}\sigma(B_s),$$
determines a positive matrix $S\in \text{Mat}_{K \times K}(\mathbb{C})$ through the  Cauchy–Schwarz inequality? Shouldn't such a innequality only be valid for $|\sigma(B_r^*B_s)|^2 \leq \sigma(B_r^*B_r)\sigma(B_s^*B_s)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, I'll show that $M_{rs} = \sigma(B^\ast_rB_s)$ is a positive matrix. To do so, it suffices to prove, for any $\hat{x} = (x_r) \in \mathbb{C}^K$, we have $\langle \hat{x}, M\hat{x}\rangle = \sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}\sigma(B^\ast_rB_s)x_s \geq 0$. But $\sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}\sigma(B^\ast_rB_s)x_s = \sigma(\sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}B^\ast_rx_sB_s)$. Set $B = \sum_s x_sB_s$, then $\sigma(\sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}B^\ast_rx_sB_s) = \sigma(B^\ast B) \geq 0$. Thus, $\langle \hat{x}, M\hat{x}\rangle \geq 0$.

For the second question, this is not true in general. Indeed, $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\sigma(x) = 2x$ is positive. Let $K = 1$, $B_1 = 1$, then $S = \sigma(1) - |\sigma(1)|^2 = -2$, which is not positive. I'm assuming you actually want $\sigma$ to be a state, i.e., $\sigma(1) = 1$. In that case this is indeed true. Again, we only need to verify, for any $\hat{x} = (x_r) \in \mathbb{C}^K$, $\langle \hat{x}, S\hat{x}\rangle = \sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}[\sigma(B^\ast_rB_s) - \overline{\sigma(B_r)}\sigma(B_s)]x_s \geq 0$. We have,

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}[\sigma(B^\ast_rB_s) - \overline{\sigma(B_r)}\sigma(B_s)]x_s &= \sigma(\sum_{r, s} \bar{x_r}B^\ast_rx_sB_s) - \overline{\sigma(\sum_s x_sB_s)}\sigma(\sum_s x_sB_s)\\
&= \sigma(B^\ast B) - \overline{\sigma(B)}\sigma(B)\\
&= \sigma(B^\ast B) - |\sigma(B)|^2
\end{split}$$

where again $B = \sum_s x_sB_s$. Since $B = B \cdot 1$, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\sigma(B)|^2 \leq \sigma(B^\ast B) \sigma(1^\ast 1) = \sigma(B^\ast B)$. Thus, $\sigma(B^\ast B) - |\sigma(B)|^2 \geq 0$, so $\langle \hat{x}, S\hat{x}\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, in the second case it really was a state.